# Fastest way to find the smallest interval of a number

Tags: algorithms

Here is my problem : Given a range, let's say 0 to 10.000, and some numbers in that range (like 23, 1456, 280, 3586), I want to find, for any input x, the two closest numbers to x, the smaller one the greater one. For example for x=100, the two numbers are 23 and 280, for x=350 they are 280 and 1456.

Is there a faster way to do that than a binary search on the list of numbers ? I vaguely remember the existence of a data structure for this task, but in my case the numbers are dynamic and will change during the execution of my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant phrase is ​ "predecessor search" .

For that, you can dynamically choose whether-or-not equality is allowed by

for each number in the range, storing 2 times that number rather than that number directly

and
for each actual query q, submitting ​ (2*q) ± 1 ​ instead of q,

where the sign depends on whether you want to allow equality

and
dividing by 2 before returning

.

With that, the greater one can be found using predecessor search in the negatives of

the actual numbers. ​ ​ ​ For your case, you could simply reverse the range, like storing

10000-23,10000-1456,10000-280,10000-3586 ​ rather than ​ 23,1456,280,3586 .

[Page 6 of this pdf](http://madalgo.au.dk/~gerth/aa15/slides/ram.pdf#page=6) gives upper bounds for dynamic predecessor searching

and references for data structures achieving those bounds.

[This pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3045.pdf) gives another data structure which does what you want and much more.